# Does the sum of power supply in circuit equal zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

Just like in the question, I want to know if the sum of power supply in the circuit is really equal zero and if it is true what is the reason behind it. For what I think, power supply shouldn't be negative so the sum wouldn't be zero. But I come across this problem

> This figue shows five elements. If $P_1=-205W$, $P_2=60W$, $P_4=45W$, $P_5=30W$, calculate the power $P_3$ received or delivered by element three.

[image]

They're giving the negative power supply, and for the solution they put the sum to be zero,
\begin{equation}
\sum P=0\\
P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4+P_5=0\\
\Longrightarrow P_3=70W
\end{equation}

That's why I'm very confused right now

Comment: Positive power in this nomenclature indicates an element that is dissipating (absorbing) power.  Negative indicates an element that is producing power or delivering power to the circuit.  PIn=Pout

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @relayman357 how do we know which is $P_in$ or $P_out$? In the solution they put $+$ in front of $P_3$. But why is that?

Comment: Hi @user635988, sorry, been busy.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two typical approaches electrical engineers use in this regard.  Pick one and be consistent and the math will work out.  In the first approach ([passive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) sign convention) a source of power to a circuit (e.g. battery) well have a negative power. It is reasonable for the source to have a positive power here as well - it would just mean that it is absorbing power (e.g. charging a battery).  In this passive approach, elements with positive power are absorbing power from the circuit (e.g. resistors heating up).

The active sign convention is just the opposite.  You can just stick with the passive and the math will work out fine.  All powers must add up to zero (power delivered = power received).

[image]